# CodeIgniter4 - Controller or Method Not Found When Using Routing Groups and Subdirectory in Controllers

Tags: codeigniter, routes, controller, codeigniter-4

I have a controller here: `/app/Controllers/Admin/AdminDashboardController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class AdminDashboardController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('pages/admin');
    }    
}
```

And in the Routes (`app/Config/Routes.php`), I added a Grouped Route like this:

```
$routes->group('admin', ['filter' => 'authGuard'], static function ($routes) {
    $routes->get('/', 'Admin\AdminDashboardController::index');
});
```

But I got a 404 error saying this:

> Controller or its method is not found:
> \App\Controllers\Admin\AdminDashboardController::index

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller namespace is `App\Controllers`. For your route to work the namespace would have to be `App\Controllers\Admin`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class AdminDashboardController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('pages/admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't worked. It is showing the same error message

Comment: @VppMan Just implemented your setup in a new project and it works just fine for me. See the updated answer for the controller code.